# How do I number records returned from a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have records ordered by date from a database, I would like to add a number corresponding according to how the record is ordered. E.g, if a record was ordered by a given date I would like to add an incrementing number to it:

```
1). Me
2). You
3). Us
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over them with an index. E.g. using http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index

Answer (score 0):

Use index method that is defined in an Array

Comment: it tends to start from zero is their any way around that.